# Extract date text from string

Tags: r

I would like to extract date from the following list  of text:

```
[[1]]
[1] "TAX INVOICE      28 Dec 2018       PO2222"

[[2]]
[1] "TAX INVOICE      20 Nov 2018       PO11111"
```

The result would be a list or a data frame:

```
 28-Dec-2018
 20-Nov-2018
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `lapply` and `gsub`:

```
lst <- list("TAX INVOICE      28 Dec 2018       PO2222",
            "TAX INVOICE      20 Nov 2018       PO11111")

lapply(lst, function(x) gsub(".*(\\d{2} \\w{3} \\d{4}).*", "\\1", x))
[[1]]
[1] "28 Dec 2018"

[[2]]
[1] "20 Nov 2018"
```

### Demo