# Extracting Date from text using R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

My dataframe looks like

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(c("2 June 2004, 5 words, ()(","profit, Insight, 2 May 2004, 188 words,  reports, by ()("), stringsAsFactors = F), "split")
```

What I want is to split column for date and words So far I found 
"[Extract date text from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061814/extract-date-text-from-string)"

```
lapply(df2, function(x) gsub(".*(\\d{2} \\w{3} \\d{4}).*", "\\1", x))
```

But its not working with my example, thanks for the help as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is only a single column, we can directly use `gsub/sub` after extracting the column.  In the pattern, the days can be 1 or more, similarly the words have 3 ('May') or 4 characters ('June'), so we need to make those changes

```
sub(".*\\b(\\d{1,} \\w{3,4} \\d{4}).*", "\\1", df$split)
#[1] "2 June 2004" "2 May 2004"
```